# Teminology: Partitioning a Set Including Empty Partitions

Tags: terminology, set-partition

Mostly I see a partition of a set A defined as a collection of non-empty disjoint sets whose union is A.

I see one reference that allows empty sets to be included in the partition: ("Potter, M. "Set theory and its philosophy", 2004, Oxford University Press, p. 130)
"Definition. A collection B of subsets of A is a partition of A if each element of A belongs to exactly one element of B.

Is there some commonly used terminology to refer to a "partition" including empty sets ?

(The context: a set of injections on the sets of a "partition" of A mapping to the set C comprises a bijection iff their images form a "partition" of C. Clearly this is true if empty sets map to empty sets, but it gets somewhat unwieldy to keep adding this in.)

Comment: If one excludes the empty set from belonging to a partition of $X$, you get a bijection between the set of partitions of $X$ and the set of equivalence relations on $X$.

Comment: If P is a partition of A, the question is looking for a standard term for a set P U { {} }, e.g. "pseudo-partition", "quasi-partition", ?

Comment: We exclude $1$ as a prime because it would break the fundamental theorem of arithmetic by allowing non-unique representations. I feel the same is true here which is why the empty set is excluded. If you allow a single empty partition which always maps to another empty partition then you can simply replace it with a token and ignore that it's the empty set.